# tumblr custom pages and ask page

Tags: themes, tumblr

I'm creating a custom tumblr theme. Both the ask (/ask) and custom pages (/whatever-you-want) seem to be considered text posts:

```
{block:PermalinkPage}
    <div>THIS IS A PERMALINK PAGE</div>
    {block:Posts}
        {block:Text}
            {block:Title}<h2>THIS IS THE ASK OR CUSTOM PAGE TITLE: {Title}</h2>{/block:Title}
            <!-- BOTH /ASK IFRAME BOX AND CUSTOM PAGES ARE PLACED HERE -->
            THIS IS THE ASK IFRAME OR CUSTOM PAGE BODY: {Body}
        {/block:Text}
    {/block:Posts}
{/block:PermalinkPage}
```

I want to have a totally different layout for the ask page and the custom pages (no headers or footers on the custom page, no title, etc) and I don't care about the (real) text posts, because I'm not going to use them. Is there a way to have a different content from the "/ask" and the custom page without using javascript? I have read the [documentation](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes), but don't see anything that would allow me to do that... Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!

Just create a new page (towards the bottom of the Customise options).

If you choose Custom Layout, you can add any html you want and it will be detached from the main template.

Here is an example: http://madox-test.tumblr.com/test

If you check the site root you can see the tumblr template: http://madox-test.tumblr.com (which can still be used for other pages too).

Ref: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/pages#layouts

Luke

Comment: Ah wait, you actually want to offer this as part of a theme? I think that is more tricky, the only way I would know how to do it would be to hack it. Surely you would need to let the user decide what pages they want to style and not style? Or are you saying any page that is not the index page (but this would apply to post pages, and tagged/ etc).

Comment: To expand on the answer and comment. For a custom ask page, you would need to use a combination of 'Pages/Custom Layout' and use the Tumblr API to submit the question (The original ask box is an iframe). As for supplying as a theme, just supply the standard theme html and the custom page html as two separate docs, no need for a hack.